# ¿Cómo leer la respuesta de Django con fetch JS?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Tengo un proyecto de Django en el cual hago un fetch con JS y quiero leer el mensaje que devuelve. ¿Cómo lo hago?
Mi código js:

```
       function checkHoroscope(){
            data = {
                'year':2000,
                'month':1,
                'day':1
            }
            fetch("{% url 'horoscope' %}", {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: data
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            })
        }
```

Mi vista en django:

```
    def check_horoscope(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return JsonResponse({'message':'hola'})
```

¿Cómo puedo sacar en JS el mensaje 'hola'?

Comment: por lo que sé el primer `then` devuelve una *Promesa* y tienes que resolver esa promesa con otro `fetch` y en este fetch tendrías que hacer `console.log(res.message)`

Comment: @Christian otro fetch u otro .then?

Comment: el console.log si te imprime los valores? Yo actualmente trabajo en algo usando fetch, y de seguro te puedo decir como lo hago, pero sii el console.log no te funciona, no se obtiene nada de tu endpoint

Comment: @AlfaRojo El console log devuelve una promesa y además con las herramientas de desarrollador en network puedo ver la petición y los datos devueltos son correctos

Comment: Un console.log no devuelve promesa, el que te lo está devolviendo es el fetch

Comment: @AlfaRojo Sí, perdona, cuando uso el log me devuelve un objeto, [object Response]

Comment: Perdón si es otro `then`

Comment: @Christian cuando pongo `fetch...}).then(res => { }).then(res1 => console.log(res1))` me devuelve undefined. ¿Es así?

Comment: Nop, debe ser `fetch...}).then(res => res.json()).then(res1 => console.log(res1))`

Comment: @Christian ha funcionado!! Escríbelo en una respuesta, te lo doy por válido y ayudamos a más miembros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una petición es un trabajo de demora un tiempo y del cual no se obtiene una respuesta inmediata del servidor. En JavaScript las peticiones se manejan con `XMLHttpRequest` o con `fecth` (solución más actual), `fetch` permite hacer peticiones a un servidor, y para el manejo de las respuestas se puede optar por 3 cosas: `callbacks`, el uso de `then` y el uso de `async/await`. La forma más común es con el uso de `then` que espera a que al resultado del servidor y resuelve la promesa.

En tu caso con el primer `then` se esta resolviendo la promesa, pero aún queda algo pendiente que sería la respuesta del servidor. Para resolver esta otra necesitamos otro `then`, pero modificando el primero.

```js
    fetch({
      ...
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(info=> console.log(info.message))
}
```

En el primer `then` especificamos que la respuesta del servidor sea resulta o tratada como Json y el resultado de esto pasará al siguiente `then` en donde ya podemos acceder al resultado final

Answer (score 1):

Según me mencionas en los comentarios, la consola si te imprime un objeto, con eso es suficiente para saber que si te obtiene datos. Ahora, resolviendo tu duda sobre como manipularlos, yo actualmente lo que hago en mi trabajo es, modificando tu fetch

```
            //Asigna una variable a tu fetch para poderla retornar
            try{
            data = fetch("{% url 'horoscope' %}", {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: data
            }).then((res) => res.json())//Conviertelo a json para un facil manejo
            }catch (err){
                console.error(err);//Recuerda que siempre puede ocurrir un error
            })
    return await data; //Con esto ya puedes manejarlo donde invocas al método
```

Otra forma que tambien he manejado, es con `.then()` y usando variables dentro, te enseño como:

```
            let returned;//La variable a retornar
            try{
            await fetch("{% url 'horoscope' %}", {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: data
            }).then((res) => res.json())//Conviertelo a json para un facil manejo
            .then(value => returned = value);//Asignas lo que te retorna a una variable para modificarla
            }catch (err){
                console.error(err);//Recuerda que siempre puede ocurrir un error
            })
    return returned; //Con esto ya puedes manejarlo donde invocas al método
```

Asignando una variable, puedes manipular de forma que desees.
Espero no haberme comido alguna llave